# How to change Html.DropdownListFor() value or selected item

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Anunt.Category, new SelectList(new List<string>()), "Categorie", new { @class = "form-control background", @Id = "categorieDropDown" })
```

```
var category = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model.Anunt.Category))
console.log(category);
categorieDropDown.value = category;
```

As it s written here it does not change everything and the category is right

How to change the value of the dropdownlist or the selected item since i want to change it with an option of the dropdown

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Since you're using JavaScript code, please also include the relevant client-side code as it exists in the browser, not just the server-side code which generates it.

Comment: For starters it looks like your list is empty..

Comment: Yes, i know, i put options from an api

Comment: No js errors in browser console